# How do you solve $(F o F^{-1})(x)$ for $\\ \frac{e^{ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 +1})} - e^{-ln(x + x\sqrt{x^2 +1})}}{2}\\$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm am to find the inverse function of $\dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$ which I believe is $\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 +1}$).  But I'm having difficulty in proving it.

This is as far as I can get with $(F \circ F^{-1})$ and I don't know how to take it further: $$
\frac12\left( e^{ \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 +1})} - e^{ -\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 +1})} \right)\\
x = \frac12 \left( e^{ \ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} - e^{ -\ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} \right) \\
2x = e^{ \ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} - \frac{1}{e^{ \ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})}} \\
2xe^{ \ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} = e^{2\ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} - 1 \\
0 = e^{2ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} - 2xe^{ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})} - 1 $$

Denote $U = e^{\ln(y + \sqrt{y^2 +1})}$

$$0 = U^2 -2xU - 1 \\ 
U = \frac{2x+-2\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{2} \\
U = x +-\sqrt{x^2 + 1} $$

Since $U = e^x$, then  $e^x = x +\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$

From here, I have no idea where to go to finish this so that $(F \circ F^{-1})(x) = x$.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$. Note that
$$f(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2e^x}$$
Thus
$$\begin{align} f(g(x))&=\frac{e^{2\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}-1}{2e^{\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}} \\
&=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2-1}{2(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})} \\
&=\frac{x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+(x^2+1)-1}{2(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})} \\
&=\frac{2x(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}{2(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})} \\
&=x
\end{align}$$
Do not forget to also check $g(f(x))=x$. Then we can guarantee that $g=f^{-1}$.

$\textbf{Edit: }$I add another way to find the inverse function of $f$. Recall that $y=f(x)\,\Leftrightarrow \, x=f^{-1}(y)$.
Then, set $$y=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
(we want to isolate the $x$ from here) so:
$$y=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2e^x}$$
$$2ye^x=e^{2x}-1$$
$$(e^x)^2-2y(e^x)-1=0$$
then, we use the general formula to solve quadratic equations and gives us
$$e^x=\frac{2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2+4}}{2}=y \pm \sqrt{y^2+1}$$
we are left with the positive option (which is obtained with $+$) because $e^x>0$ for all $x$. Thus
$$e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$$
and then
$$x=\log\big(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\big)$$
which is nothing more than $f^{-1}(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)=\dfrac{e^x-e{-x}}2$

so that $x=f^{-1}(y)$

$$(e^x)^2-2e^x y-1=0$$

$e^x=\dfrac{2y\pm\sqrt{4y^2+4}}2$

As $e^x>0,e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1},x=?$

Comment: Thank you for that.  You showed me that I had a typo and fix it.  :)